# NuGet Package default package removed

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package, vs-web-site-project

I created a new website in VS2015, then I removed some of the NuGet packages.

This caused the project (website) build to fail. I created a new project (website) again. That build was also to fail.

For example I get the error:

> Error BC30002 Type 'BundleCollection' is not defined.

Project not defined app_code folder and .cs files and did not run.

And I created a new project (ASP.NET MVC or Web Form). This also failed to build.

I use `Update-Package -reinstall`, Not again

Comment: You need to completely rebuild references to the package you removed are still in the object files.  I normally delete the bin folder and then rebuild which will force everything to recompile.  I recommend backing up the bin folder before deleting in case some of the reference items do not get moved to bin folder.

Comment: @jdweng Thank's. I doing but Failed again

Comment: Is it same error?  Do you have BundleCollection in your remaining code?  Do you have other projects referenced in your code?  Did they rebuild?  Check the dates of the executables in the bin folder and make sure all recompiled with new data.  Sometimes what happens is you are using the Release Version but you rebuilt the Debug version (or one of the referenced projects).

Comment: @jdweng yes i do. Even I Creat New Project But Failed

Comment: What is the error?  The NuGet is still being reference.  Open up solution explorer and make sure it is not being reference by project.  Also check any other project that is in the reference to make sure those project do not have reference and are rebuilt.  You can also open up the .proj with notepad and make sure it is not being called by anything in the project file

Comment: Running Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization will solve the issue that you are facing.

Comment: @JayotiParkash I have error in all .cs file , not only BundleConfig.cs . I think nuget package files removed from Microsoft Visual Studio installed folder

Comment: I have error in all .cs file , not only BundleConfig.cs . I think nuGet package files removed from Microsoft Visual Studio installed folder .

Comment: @jdweng . i unistall VS and install again that solved. thank's for your help :)

Comment: Uninstall VS and Reinstall would just of changed the default Net Version.  Should of had nothing to do with issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to update your Visual Studio , because older versions have outdated templates with old package references.

But you can update these templates manulally too. First try to run the following command:

```
PM> Update-Package
```

It will update all of your decencies at once.

Or you can just install the latest package which contains the `BundleCollection`:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
```

And then update your MVC dependencies:

```
PM> update-package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
PM> update-package Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
```

After that, search for all of the `web.config` files in your solution (there should be at least 2 of them) and then correct the old assembly versions in them. It's very important. Otherwise you will be able to compile your project but you won't be able to run it.

Comment: No, i creat Website not MVC project , I have error in all .cs file , not only BundleConfig.cs. I think nuget package files removed from Microsoft Visual Studio installed folder

Comment: A repair can fix this. Find the Visual Studio Installer on your computer. For example, on a computer running Windows 10, select Start, and then scroll to the letter V, where it's listed as Visual Studio Installer. Open the installer, choose More, and then choose Repair.

Comment: I do that but failed, So i unistall VS and install again that solved. thank's for your help :)